# Generalizing or theorizing or abstracting?

Tags: word-choice, word-meaning, difference

Consider the following statement:

> He has blood on his hands and a knife, he must have stabbed somebody.

Now if I change the above statement to:

> If a man has blood on his hands and a knife, he must have stabbed somebody.

What am I doing? Am I **theorizing**, or **abstracting**, or **generalizing**, or something else? 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Both sentences are "jumping to a conclusion" or "jumping to an erroneous conclusion".

I have had blood on my hands while holding a knife. It was because I was clumsy and had cut myself. There are jobs in meat and fish handling where people get blood on their hands while holding a knife.

The sentence that starts "He had ..." might be regarded as theorizing. Given some observations (blood on hands, knife) you form a theory about the cause.